# CORS request not working in windows safari version in 51.1.7

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, safari, cors

CORS request not working in Windows Safari
I am making a CORS request to upload a file i am using Plupload plugin to upload a file . This works fine in chrome, 
however when I run in safari I get an ' Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.'. 
  I have set the CORS on the server.

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
               EnableCrossDomainAjaxCall();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                ErrorHandlerTools.LogError(ex);
            }
        }
 private void EnableCrossDomainAjaxCall()
        { 
           // if (ValidateRequest())
          //  {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
                Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Methods");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "HEAD, GET, PUT, POST, COPY, OPTIONS, DELETE");

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Headers");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin,x-requested-with,content-Type,accept,x-auth-token,x-custom-header");

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Max-Age");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                } 
            //}
        }
```

This is Request headers

```
Origin: http://localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryLUZFR1paN3ARVMRv
Referer: http://localhost/PetaTracker/UploadView/machineView/LargeFile
```

Can anyone let me know where i am going wrong
It will be very kind of you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<AllowedHeader>origin</AllowedHeader>
```

in the configuration.

Comment: Thank u for replying i have added orgin   HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Headers");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin,x-requested-with,content-Type,accept,x-auth-token,x-custom-header") but it doest not work

Comment: can you debug and check if the code inside the if block is executing.
Additionally, replace 
Response.AddHeader
with 
Response.AppendHeader

Comment: Actually there was no problem in CORS the problem was the browser was not supporting  FileReader object i was uploading large files by splitting them in chunks but the browser was not supporting File Reader